# New prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

I’m just reading some articles on the internet and saw an article that says that there’s found a New prime number. Is that true? Do we last week have 
found a New one?

https://www.ad.nl/economie/grootste-priemgetal-ooit-ontdekt~a33478f2/

Comment: Can you add a link to an English article? I don't speak Dutch, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $2^{77,232,917}-1$ [with $23,249,425$ digits](http://www.mersenne.org/primes/digits/M77232917.zip) found in the Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search (GIMPS)

See https://www.mersenne.org/primes/press/M77232917.html for the announcement

Answer (score 1):

Finding a new prime number is not something that you'll see in the news. What happened a few days ago was that it was found [a prime number larger than any other known prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number).